# Windows Forms' Appearance

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, forms, excel, userform

Just started using Visual Studio 2008 and was hoping to convert my VBA UserForms to VB.NET with the intent of upgrading my antiquated `UserForm` controls to newer Windows form controls that match the operating system.

The Windows forms I create in Visual Studio look great, but when I load them in PowerPoint or Excel, the form controls look just as ugly as they did before (e.g. plain, rectangular buttons).

Is there a way to employ modern controls in my Windows forms using VB.NET in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either use one of the many available custom drawn buttons. Or it could be that you have to turn on visual style to make them render better http://dotnet.mvps.org/dotnet/faqs/?id=xpvisualstyles&lang=en